# How to record only human voice and avoid bg noise using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, ios, voice, avaudiorecorder, recording

I'm making a iOS app like *Talking Tom* and unable to record only human voice. It gets so much background noise along with the human voice and hence its not, accurate like *Talking Tom*.

I wonder there must some record settings be present to use with `AVAudiorecorder` which would help me in this context. I am just using the default record settings for now with `AVAudioRecorder`.

Comment: did you able to solve this problem. I am also facing the same problem. Please help me if you could able to solve this.